# How do I create a limited admin group that can only access 1 group on the AD in Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

This is what I am looking for.  I want to created a limited domain admin group that really only has access to be able to create, disable, and do password resets for a particular group on the AD.  Is there a way to limit admin right down this far.  This group would not need rights to do any changes to end clients, or any other groups with in the AD.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve almost what you want my delegating permissions in Active Directory, *however*, I think the lowest you can go is by Organisational Unit. I do not know of a way to limit influence by security groups.

Source:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732524.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there a way to limit them from even seeing the other folders?

Comment: +1; but you don't don't have to delegate permissions on an OU, you can set the security on individual objects within AD.